# scipy.stats.norm.interval returning inf

Tags: python, scipy.stats

I have a bunch of data points and a model and I am now looking to compute at what confidence level I can rule out the model.

I am starting with a chi squared value accompanied by a value for the number of degrees of freedom.

Using scipy, what I have been trying looks like this:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2
from scipy.stats import norm

chisq = 74.1
df = 21 #degrees of freedom

cdf = chi2.cdf(chisq, df,scale=1)
sigma = norm.interval(cdf)
```

This produces the output I am looking for (5.5 sigma confidence), but fails for higher chi^2 values.

It looks to me like the problem is with the precision of the data type that scipy uses. For a chi^2 value 334.7 (and the same number of degrees of freedom) the chi2.cdf yields 1.0 which in turn makes norm.interval return -inf/inf. This should preferably return a 16.1 sigma confidence.

I found a way to get better precision for the cdf using mpmath:

```
import mpmath

mpmath.mp.dps = 200 # decimal digits of precision

def cdf(x,k):
    x,k = mpmath.mpf(x), mpmath.mpf(k)
    return mpmath.gammainc(k/2, 0, x/2, regularized=True)
```

However, the problem persist as it seems scipy.stats.norm.interval rounds the input to 1.0.

Is there a way to circumvent this by changing the data type norm.interval uses or are there other ways/packages to compute the endpoints of a normal distribution with arbitrary precision input?

Answer (score 0):

Most SciPy features work in double (64-bit) precision; they do not support arbitrary precision arithmetic. When `chisq = 334.7`, the CDF is numerically indistinguishable from `1.0`. However, the complement of the CDF, the survival function, is still representable. Using the fact that the normal distribution is symmetric, you can use the inverse survival function of the normal distribution to get your sigma value.

```py
from scipy.stats import chi2, norm

chisq = 334.7 
df = 21  # degrees of freedom

sf = chi2.sf(chisq, df, scale=1)  # 2.6070172877893564e-58
sigma = norm.isf(sf/2)  # 16.098657051475882
```